# Where should I store a Python3 module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, getch

I'm using a Raspberry Pi with the Raspbian OS. I just installed Python3's `getch` module typing `pip install py-getch` at the shell. This is the text  showed on the shell:

```
Collecting py-getch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/ef/51cb247eb54a40ef1808dc3b1c7ed2630626266f31f6d5a976cd0696b554/py-getch-1.0.1.zip

Building wheels for collected packages: py-getch
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for py-getch ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/ed/eb/a2/042eb5548cdb9f671685882c854a525969e5c62a2b79c39df2
Successfully built py-getch
Installing collected packages: py-getch
Successfully installed py-getch-1.0.1
```

Then, I opened Xarchiver and extracted the files at the `/home/pi` directory. If I open the Python3 IDLE at this directory and type `import getch` I get no error and all the code works. But if I go to the `/home/pi/Desktop` directory and type the same, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'getch'
```

So, my question is: where sould I store this or any other Python module to be able to import them from all the directories? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not where the files were installed. That's where pip cached the installer. It sounds like pip did not actually install py-getch, and the error messages from your installation attempt would have helped a lot with understanding why.

Comment: (Or perhaps you installed it for the wrong Python.)

Comment: I think I didn't get any error message. I'm going to post the full text the shell generated while installing it.

Comment: It sounds like you installed it for the wrong Python, then.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a virtual environment for each of your projects (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Just create a venv folder in the root directory of your project and activate the environment before you start working on your project.

Edit: Of course this is no solution for your problem, but the best way to start a python project. And if you would use a venv you wouldn't have problems like that. To solve your problem, read the answer below and edit your pythonpath.

Answer (score 0):

I believe where you store it is less important than simply making sure the location is part of your PATH. Try adding the current folder to the PATH and see if that corrects the issue.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an answer to my question. You can see all the directories that are included in your PYTHONPATH by typing `import sys` at the Python IDLE, and then `print(sys.path)`. The only thing you have to do is to store the module folder at one of these directories.

Comment: Doing this manually is going to cause bad interactions with the standard Python module installation mechanisms.